# monotonously increasing error in fhat evaluation points when ploting kde.local.test results from ks package

Tags: r, distribution, kernel-density

I have trouble plotting the results from `kde.local.test` function (`ks` package from R) testing for local differences in the kernel density between two samples with a two-dimensional kernel density estimation

I prepared two examples. Example 1 works, example 2 does not. Why?

**Example #1:** doesn't work

```
data("iris")  
dat <- iris[order(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length),]  
x1 <- iris[1:75,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]  
x2 <- iris[76:150,c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")]  
H1samse <- Hpi(x1, pre = "scale", nstage = 2, pilot = "samse") 
H2samse <- Hpi(x2, pre = "scale", nstage = 2, pilot = "samse")  
loct <- kde.local.test(x1,x2, H1 = H1samse, H2 = H2samse)  
plot(loct)
```

Results in the following error:

```
Error in .filled.contour(fhat$eval.points[[1]], fhat$eval.points[[2]],  : 
  invalid contour values: have to increase strictly monotonously
```

**Example #2:** works fine

```
data("crabs")  
x1 <- crabs[crabs$sex=="M", c("FL", "RW")]  
x2 <- crabs[crabs$sex=="F", c("FL", "RW")]  
H1samse <- Hpi(x1, pre = "sphere", nstage = 2, pilot = "samse")  
H2samse <- Hpi(x2, pre = "sphere", nstage = 2, pilot = "samse")  
loct <- kde.local.test(x1,x2, H1 = H1samse, H2 = H2samse)  
plot(loct)  
H1scv<- Hscv(x1)  
H2scv <- Hscv(x2)  
loct <- kde.local.test(x1,x2, H1 = H1scv, H2 = H2scv)  
plot(loct)
```